# How should I fix eslint warning (React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency) and a loop caused by the warning?

Tags: reactjs

In following codes, eslint will give a warning.

```
Line 24:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchPosts'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Layout } from './Layout';
import { TwitterPost, reloadTwitterEmbedTemplate } from '../TwitterPost';
import '../../styles/pages/TimelinePage.css'
import axios from 'axios';

export const TimelinePage = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const location = useLocation();

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/posts', { params: { page: page } });
    setPosts(posts.concat(res.data));
    reloadTwitterEmbedTemplate();
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname !== '/') return;

    fetchPosts();
  }, [location]);

  const postTemplates = posts.map((post: any) => {
    if (post.media_name === 'twitter') return <TwitterPost mediaUserScreenName={post.media_user_screen_name} mediaPostId={post.media_post_id} />;
    return null;
  });

  return(
    <Layout body={
      <div id="timeline">
        <div>{postTemplates}</div>
        <div className="show-more-box">
          <button type="button" className="show-more-button" onClick={fetchPosts}>show more</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    } />
  );
};
```

I fixed the warning by adding `fetchPosts`. Then I followed eslint instructions using `useCallback` and adding variables used in `fetchPosts` to deps. This change causes a loop. How should I fix the loop and eslint warning?

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Layout } from './Layout';
import { TwitterPost, reloadTwitterEmbedTemplate } from '../TwitterPost';
import '../../styles/pages/TimelinePage.css'
import axios from 'axios';

export const TimelinePage = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const location = useLocation();

  const fetchPosts = useCallback(async () => {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/posts', { params: { page: page } });
    setPosts(posts.concat(res.data));
    reloadTwitterEmbedTemplate();
    setPage(page + 1);
  }, [page, posts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname !== '/') return;

    fetchPosts();
  }, [location, fetchPosts]);

  const postTemplates = posts.map((post: any) => {
    if (post.media_name === 'twitter') return <TwitterPost mediaUserScreenName={post.media_user_screen_name} mediaPostId={post.media_post_id} />;
    return null;
  });

  return(
    <Layout body={
      <div id="timeline">
        <div>{postTemplates}</div>
        <div className="show-more-box">
          <button type="button" className="show-more-button" onClick={fetchPosts}>show more</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    } />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to really understand what's going on when you use the useEffect hook. It talks, among other things, about your exact problem and ways to solve it. That said, you should move the function inside the useEffect callback, something like:

```
export const TimelinePage = () => {
  /* ... */

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.pathname !== '/') return;
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/posts', { params: { page: page } });
        setPosts(posts.concat(res.data));
        reloadTwitterEmbedTemplate();
        setPage(page + 1);
    }
    fetchPosts();
  }, [location]);

  /* ... */
};
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But that's not right. I also use `fetchPosts` in my template, so I have to move the function outside the `useEffect`. But I need to know how to fix the warning and the loop described in my question.

Comment: Yes, I see that you do. I highly encourage you to read the article I linked, but also - why do you need to re-fetch the posts when the user clicks the button? Why not simply increase the page state when the user clicks the button, which will rerender the component with the new page state and re-run the effect, fetching the posts based on the new page state?

Comment: That works. I need to change the page state on button click. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it